# When I turn Discord bot restart, the buttons and interactions don't work anymore

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

I wrote a bot with Discord.py, which automatically exchanges when you press the exchange button, and my problem is that when I turn the bot off and on, I need to send the exchange message again. How can I fix this problem?

I tried to delete the previous message and send the new one when the bot is turned on again, and I don't think it's a good solution, and I don't use any other library like Discord Components, maybe the problem is here, but it doesn't make sense that this library is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that for an interaction to be responded to, your bot needs to contain a registered callback for that component. Whenever you restart your bot, all views (which contain component-related callbacks) are lost. You need to re-add these views every time your bot starts, making these views persistent. Here's an example of persistent views:

```py
# This example requires the 'message_content' privileged intent to function.

from discord.ext import commands
import discord


# Define a simple View that persists between bot restarts
# In order for a view to persist between restarts it needs to meet the following conditions:
# 1) The timeout of the View has to be set to None
# 2) Every item in the View has to have a custom_id set
# It is recommended that the custom_id be sufficiently unique to
# prevent conflicts with other buttons the bot sends.
# For this example the custom_id is prefixed with the name of the bot.
# Note that custom_ids can only be up to 100 characters long.
class PersistentView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label='Green', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id='persistent_view:green')
    async def green(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message('This is green.', ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label='Red', style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id='persistent_view:red')
    async def red(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message('This is red.', ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label='Grey', style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id='persistent_view:grey')
    async def grey(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message('This is grey.', ephemeral=True)


class PersistentViewBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True

        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('$'), intents=intents)

    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        # Register the persistent view for listening here.
        # Note that this does not send the view to any message.
        # In order to do this you need to first send a message with the View, which is shown below.
        # If you have the message_id you can also pass it as a keyword argument, but for this example
        # we don't have one.
        self.add_view(PersistentView())

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')
        print('------')


bot = PersistentViewBot()


@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def prepare(ctx: commands.Context):
    """Starts a persistent view."""
    # In order for a persistent view to be listened to, it needs to be sent to an actual message.
    # Call this method once just to store it somewhere.
    # In a more complicated program you might fetch the message_id from a database for use later.
    # However this is outside of the scope of this simple example.
    await ctx.send("What's your favourite colour?", view=PersistentView())


bot.run('token')
```

- Reference: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py